# What sort of information is saved in a PSD file?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, psd

Up until recently I was working for a graphic design office that was closed down. What I want to know is if all the work I have done there and saved as psd can be proved somehow (perhaps by tracking the information in the file) that it did not come from original software.

I do not want to have any legal problems in case I want to re-use/alter my psds and all my saved work. Will the possible embedded tracking information change if I load and save the psd again from another legally purchased copy of Photoshop?

P.S The layers and all the work within the file belongs 100% to me. It is the copy of photoshop they had in the office I am worried about.

Answer (score 1):

From glancing at the [PSD file format specification](http://www.adobe.com/devnet-apps/photoshop/fileformatashtml/) I don't think any such information is stored in the file.